# Bootstrap popover position when container moves

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have used 4 bootstrap popovers on trigger focus. At a time only one popover display.
On click on anchor tag parent container moves to left but popover stay on its place and it does not move with container.

How i can move popover with container. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide some code snippets so I can further help you but here is what I suggest:

- Only use one popover as it easier to maintain the position and visibility of one popover instead of 4. Make this popover globally available.
- Create a custom event handler to update your popover. The popover should listen to the event and the anchor tag parent container should throw the event whenever it moves. Such that the popover can update its position.

Comment: Thanks for reply...but I have 4 different anchor tag and 4 different popover. Also when click on left anchor tag contaner moves to right and when click on right anchor tag container moves to left. but popover stays on it place and does not move